# What Is The Difference Between idTokenClaims and idToken In Azure JWT?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, jwt

When I authenticate with Azure AD I get a JWT that looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "logout": "ƒ () {}",
  "login": "ƒ () {}",
  "authenticationState": "Authenticated",
  "accountInfo": {
    "account": {
      "idToken": {
        "exp": 1111111111,
        "nbf": 1111111111,
        "ver": "1.0",
        "iss": "https://corp.b2clogin.com/1234-hash-abcd/v2.0/",
        "sub": "1234-abc-123-1234-1234",
        "aud": "1234-abc-123-1234-1234",
        "nonce": "1234-abc-123-1234-1234",
        "iat": 1111111111,
        "auth_time": 1111111111,
        "name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "extension_Role": "Admin",
        "tfp": "B2C_1_signupsignin1"
      },
      "idTokenClaims": {
        "exp": 1111111111,
        "nbf": 1111111111,
        "ver": "1.0",
        "iss": "https://corp.b2clogin.com/1234-hash-abcd/v2.0/",
        "sub": "1234-abc-123-1234-1234",
        "aud": "1234-abc-123-1234-1234",
        "nonce": "1234-abc-123-1234-1234",
        "iat": 1111111111,
        "auth_time": 1111111111,
        "name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "extension_Role": "Admin",
        "tfp": "B2C_1_signupsignin1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see `idToken` and `idTokenClaims` are identical.

Is there any reason why Azure is sending both sections?

I couldn't find any Microsoft documentation about these sections and if you are supposed to use one over the other.

I am interested in `name` and `extension_Role`. Is there any reason why I should take the value from one section over another?

For my purposes right now I can use either. However, I am interested in finding out the reason for this duplication and some explanation of which is the recommended one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, they are same.

`idToken` should be a jwt token as a string. But in the data you provided, it was decoded to json claims for a couple of reasons which we don't know.

`idTokenClaims` is all of the claims(properties) decoded from `idToken`.

So you can use either of them, but I suggest you to use `idTokenClaims` because I'm not sure if `idToken` would not be decoded in next time(and it will be a jwt token string).